# How to get corresponding type from TypeConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

In .NET I know I can get a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) for a given type as follows

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime))
```

However if given type converter object by some other means, how do I know what type it converts to?

Comment: `CanConvertTo` method might help. Don't know if it is possible with reflection.